# When a player calls against themselves, can the umpire overrule them?

Tags: rules, tennis

Can an umpire overrule a player that called against themselves?

Comment: Under what circumstances do you envisage a player calling against himself.  Surely the umpire would overrule an official, not a player.

Comment: @Chenmunka I'd guess that the OP might mean situations like this: [In An Amazing Display Of Sportsmanship, Novak Djokovic Gave His Opponent A Crucial Point](https://www.businessinsider.com/novak-djokovic-wimbledon-opponent-point-2014-6)

Answer (score 2):

Caveat: When you say "called against themselves", I assume you mean the player advocates a decision that would result in putting himself at a disadvantage.

Technically, the umpire could overrule it...but in practice he never does because the player is usually doing it in the spirit of good sportsmanship.  E.g., opponent hits a shot that gets called out but player says it was really in, so the umpire will give the opponent the point.